# Use ecore file from an other plugin

Tags: maven, acceleo

I'm trying to compile my project with maven and acceleo.

I want to generate .emtl file with acceleo maven but to generate this file I have to link it with an ecore which is in an other plugin and I don't find the solution to link the mtl file with this external ecore model.

Can someone help me please?